# Connecting Application To WebServer and Pulling Info from MYSQL Server

Tags: java, android, mysql, xml, json

I am currently building an Android application for my website http://loadedgeek.com -if you visit it, it is a forum, so i want the application to allow the users create/post topics, read topics, and also register on the site via the Application without the application opening the browser.

Now i want the user when he clicks on "View Topics" i want it to display topics on the website via its database, so the MainActivity calls the AllTopicsActivity. Which is where i have a problem, i am still a learner, so i was google searching and was combining codes together, the activity lets the user edit the topic instead of just reading the topic.

This is main.xml file

> ```
> <!--  Sample Dashboard screen with four buttons -->
> <!--  Button to view all topics screen -->
> <Button android:id="@+id/btnViewTopics"
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:text="View Topics"
>     android:layout_marginTop="25dip"/>
>
> <!--  Button to create a new topic screen -->
> <Button android:id="@+id/btnCreateTopics"
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:text="Add New Topic"
>     android:layout_marginTop="25dip"/>
>
> <!-- Button to create a loadedgeek account -->    <Button android:id="@+id/btnCreateAccount"
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:text="Create An Account"
>     android:layout_marginTop="25dip"/>
>       <!-- Button To Check For Updates -->    <Button android:id="@+id/btnCheckForUpdate"
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:text="Check For Application Update"
>     android:layout_marginTop="25dip"/>
>       <!-- Button To View Application Information -->     <Button android:id="@+id/btnViewAppDetails"
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:text="About The Application"
>     android:layout_marginTop="25dip"/>   </LinearLayout>
> ```

This is the MainActivity that calls the AllTopicsActivity when a user click the View Topic Button

> package com.loadedgeek.app;   import android.app.Activity; import
>   android.content.Intent; import android.os.Bundle; import
>   android.view.View; import android.widget.Button;   public class
>   MainActivity extends Activity{
>
> ```
> Button btnViewTopics;
> Button btnNewTopic;   Button btnCreateAccount;    Button btnCheckForUpdates;  Button btnViewAppDetails
>
> @Override
> public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.main);
>
>     // Buttons
>     btnViewTopics = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnViewTopics);
>     btnNewTopic = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCreateTopic);         btnCreateAccount = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCreateAccount);
>   btnCheckForUpdates = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCheckForUpdates);
>   btnViewAppDetails = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnViewAppDetails);
>
>     // view topics click event
>     btnViewTopics.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>
>         @Override
>         public void onClick(View view) {
>             // Launching All topics Activity
>             Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AllTopicsActivity.class);
>             startActivity(i);
>
>         }
>     });
>
>     // new topic click event
>     btnNewTopic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>
>         @Override
>         public void onClick(View view) {
>             // Launching create new topic activity
>             Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NewTopicActivity.class);
>             startActivity(i);
>
>         }
>     });
>           // create account click event
>     btnCreateAccount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>
>         @Override
>         public void onClick(View view) {
>             // Launching All topics Activity
>             Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CreateAccount.class);
>             startActivity(i);
>
>         }
>     });
>           // check for updates click event
>     btnCheckForUpdates.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>
>         @Override
>         public void onClick(View view) {
>             // Launching All topics Activity
>             Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CheckUpdates.class);
>             startActivity(i);
>
>         }
>     });
>           // view app click event
>     btnViewAppDetails.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>
>         @Override
>         public void onClick(View view) {
>             // Launching All topics Activity
>             Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AppDetails.class);
>             startActivity(i);
>
>         }
>     });
> } }
> ```

Now this is the AllTopicActivity in which i have a problem

> package com.loadedgeek.official;   import java.util.ArrayList; import
>   java.util.HashMap; import java.util.List;   import
>   org.apache.http.NameValuePair; import org.json.JSONArray; import
>   org.json.JSONException; import org.json.JSONObject;   import
>   android.app.ListActivity; import android.app.ProgressDialog; import
>   android.content.Intent; import android.os.AsyncTask; import
>   android.os.Bundle; import android.util.Log; import android.view.View;
>   import android.widget.AdapterView; import
>   android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener; import
>   android.widget.ListAdapter; import android.widget.ListView; import
>   android.widget.SimpleAdapter; import android.widget.TextView;   public
>   class AllTopicsActivity extends ListActivity {
>
> ```
> // Progress Dialog
> private ProgressDialog pDialog;
>
> // Creating JSON Parser object
> JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
>
> ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> topicsList;
>
> // url to get all products list
> private static String url_all_topics = "http://api.loadedgeek.com/android_connect/get_all_topics.php";
>
> // JSON Node names
> private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
> private static final String TAG_TOPIC = "topic";
> private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
> private static final String TAG_SUBJECT = "subject";
>
> // products JSONArray
> JSONArray products = null;
>
> @Override
> public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.topics);
>
>     // Hashmap for ListView
>     topicsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
>
>     // Loading products in Background Thread
>     new LoadAllTopics().execute();
>
>     // Get listview
>     ListView lv = getListView();
>
>     // on seleting single product
>     // launching Edit topic
>     lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
>
>         @Override
>         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
>                 int position, long id) {
>             // getting values from selected ListItem
>             String id = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.id)).getText()
>                     .toString();
>
>             // Starting new intent
>             Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
>                     EditTopicActivity.class);
>             // sending pid to next activity
>             in.putExtra(TAG_ID, id);
>
>             // starting new activity and expecting some response back
>             startActivityForResult(in, 100);
>         }
>     });
>
> }
> ```

You see that it lauch a EditTopicActivity when a user click the topic, instead of text view to read :(

it displays the topics in list view, but when a user clicks on any topic, it will display and let the user edit the topic which i dont want, i tried removing the EDit code but it scatter the whole project, so right now i need help, i want the activity to display the topic and it details in text view without letting the user edit it or delete it.. Thanks

This, is the EditTopicActivity, it contains activity to delete and update a topic which i want to avoid and remove.. it also display the edit_topic.xml file. the activity belo

> public class EditTopicActivity extends Activity {
>
> ```
> EditText txtSubject;
> EditText txtPoster;
> EditText txtMessage;
> EditText txtCreatedAt;
> Button btnSave;
> Button btnDelete;
>
> String pid;
>
> // Progress Dialog
> private ProgressDialog pDialog;
>
> // JSON parser class
> JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
>
> // single product url
> private static final String url_topic_detials = "http://api.loadedgeek.com/android_connect/get_topic_details.php";
>
> // url to update product
> private static final String url_update_topic = "http://api.loadedgeek.com/android_connect/update_topic.php";
>
> // url to delete product
> private static final String url_delete_topic = "http://api.loadedgeek.com/android_connect/delete_topic.php";
>
> // JSON Node names
> private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
> private static final String TAG_TOPIC = "topic";
> private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
> private static final String TAG_SUBJECT = "subject";
> private static final String TAG_POSTER = "poster";
> private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";
>
> @Override
> public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.edit_topic);
>
>     // save button
>     btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
>     btnDelete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);
>
>     // getting product details from intent
>     Intent i = getIntent();
>
>     // getting product id (pid) from intent
>     pid = i.getStringExtra(TAG_ID);
>
>     // Getting complete product details in background thread
>     new GetProductDetails().execute();
>
>     // save button click event
>     btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>
>         @Override
>         public void onClick(View arg0) {
>             // starting background task to update product
>             new SaveTopicDetails().execute();
>         }
>     });
>
>     // Delete button click event
>     btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>
>         @Override
>         public void onClick(View arg0) {
>             // deleting product in background thread
>             new DeleteTopic().execute();
>         }
>     });
>
> }
>
> /**
>  * Background Async Task to Get complete product details
>  * */
> class GetProductDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
>
>     /**
>      * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
>      * */
>     @Override
>     protected void onPreExecute() {
>         super.onPreExecute();
>         pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EditTopicActivity.this);
>         pDialog.setMessage("Loading Topic details. Please wait...");
>         pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
>         pDialog.setCancelable(true);
>         pDialog.show();
>     }
>
>     /**
>      * Getting product details in background thread
>      * */
>     protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
>
>         // updating UI from Background Thread
>         runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
>             public void run() {
>                 // Check for success tag
>                 int success;
>                 try {
>                     // Building Parameters
>                     List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
>                     params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pid", pid));
>
>                     // getting product details by making HTTP request
>                     // Note that product details url will use GET request
>                     JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
>                             url_topic_detials, "GET", params);
>
>                     // check your log for json response
>                     Log.d("Single Topic Details", json.toString());
>
>                     // json success tag
>                     success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
>                     if (success == 1) {
>                         // successfully received product details
>                         JSONArray topicsObj = json
>                                 .getJSONArray(TAG_TOPICS); // JSON Array
>
>                         // get first product object from JSON Array
>                         JSONObject topics = topicsObj.getJSONObject(0);
>
>                         // product with this pid found
>                         // Edit Text
>                         txtSubject = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSubject);
>                         txtPoster = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputPoster);
>                         txtMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputMessage);
>
>                         // display product data in EditText
>                         txtSubject.setText(topics.getString(TAG_SUBJECT));
>                         txtPoster.setText(topics.getString(TAG_POSTER));
>                         txtMessage.setText(topics.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
>
>                     }else{
>                         // product with pid not found
>                     }
>                 } catch (JSONException e) {
>                     e.printStackTrace();
>                 }
>             }
>         });
>
>         return null;
>     }
>
>     /**
>      * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
>      * **/
>     protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
>         // dismiss the dialog once got all details
>         pDialog.dismiss();
>     }
> }
>
> /**
>  * Background Async Task to  Save product Details
>  * */
> class SaveTopicDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
>
>     /**
>      * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
>      * */
>     @Override
>     protected void onPreExecute() {
>         super.onPreExecute();
>         pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EditTopicActivity.this);
>         pDialog.setMessage("Saving Topic ...");
>         pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
>         pDialog.setCancelable(true);
>         pDialog.show();
>     }
>
>     /**
>      * Saving product
>      * */
>     protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
>
>         // getting updated data from EditTexts
>         String name = txtName.getText().toString();
>         String price = txtPrice.getText().toString();
>         String description = txtDesc.getText().toString();
>
>         // Building Parameters
>         List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
>         params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_PID, pid));
>         params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_NAME, name));
>         params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_PRICE, price));
>         params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_DESCRIPTION, description));
>
>         // sending modified data through http request
>         // Notice that update product url accepts POST method
>         JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_update_product,
>                 "POST", params);
>
>         // check json success tag
>         try {
>             int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
>
>             if (success == 1) {
>                 // successfully updated
>                 Intent i = getIntent();
>                 // send result code 100 to notify about product update
>                 setResult(100, i);
>                 finish();
>             } else {
>                 // failed to update product
>             }
>         } catch (JSONException e) {
>             e.printStackTrace();
>         }
>
>         return null;
>     }
>
>     /**
>      * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
>      * **/
>     protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
>         // dismiss the dialog once product uupdated
>         pDialog.dismiss();
>     }
> }
>
> /*****************************************************************
>  * Background Async Task to Delete Product
>  * */
> class DeleteProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
>
>     /**
>      * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
>      * */
>     @Override
>     protected void onPreExecute() {
>         super.onPreExecute();
>         pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EditTopicActivity.this);
>         pDialog.setMessage("Deleting Topic...");
>         pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
>         pDialog.setCancelable(true);
>         pDialog.show();
>     }
>
>     /**
>      * Deleting product
>      * */
>     protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
>
>         // Check for success tag
>         int success;
>         try {
>             // Building Parameters
>             List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
>             params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", id));
>
>             // getting product details by making HTTP request
>             JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
>                     url_delete_product, "POST", params);
>
>             // check your log for json response
>             Log.d("Delete Topic", json.toString());
>
>             // json success tag
>             success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
>             if (success == 1) {
>                 // product successfully deleted
>                 // notify previous activity by sending code 100
>                 Intent i = getIntent();
>                 // send result code 100 to notify about product deletion
>                 setResult(100, i);
>                 finish();
>             }
>         } catch (JSONException e) {
>             e.printStackTrace();
>         }
>
>         return null;
>     }
>
>     /**
>      * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
>      * **/
>     protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
>         // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
>         pDialog.dismiss();
>
>     }
>
> } }
> ```

Alas, the edit_topic file

> ```
> <!-- Input Name -->
> <EditText android:id="@+id/inputSubject"
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_margin="5dip"
>     android:layout_marginBottom="15dip"
>     android:singleLine="true"/>
>
> <!-- Price Label -->
> <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:text="Your Name"
>     android:paddingLeft="10dip"
>     android:paddingRight="10dip"
>     android:paddingTop="10dip"
>     android:textSize="17dip"/>
>
> <!-- Input poster name -->
> <EditText android:id="@+id/inputPoster"
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_margin="5dip"
>     android:layout_marginBottom="15dip"
>     android:singleLine="true"/>
>
> <!-- Description Label -->
> <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:text="Topic Message"
>     android:paddingLeft="10dip"
>     android:paddingRight="10dip"
>     android:paddingTop="10dip"
>     android:textSize="17dip"/>
>
> <!-- Input description -->
> <EditText android:id="@+id/inputMessage"
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_margin="5dip"
>     android:layout_marginBottom="15dip"
>     android:lines="4"
>     android:gravity="top"/>
>
> <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:orientation="horizontal">
>     <!-- Button Csave topic -->
> <Button android:id="@+id/btnSave"
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:text="Save Changes"
>     android:layout_weight="1"/>
>
> <!-- Button Create topic -->
> <Button android:id="@+id/btnDelete"
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:text="Delete"
>     android:layout_weight="1"/>
> </LinearLayout>   </LinearLayout>
> ```

Comment: Victor, Could you post some code? Read this link http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51144/how-do-i-post-code-in-stackoverflow

Comment: I have edited again, the EditTopicActivit and edit_topic.xml posted

Comment: i just want it to display the information in a text view such that the user, cannot edit or delete the topic when he is not the owner of the site

Comment: But is it possible to display it as text? not in a way the user can attempt to edit

Comment: Ofcourse, don't pass the values to their respective urls & instead of editText use TextView if you want just to show the text.